# Calculate sum of two columns in order by clause - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to convert the below mysql query into laravel equivalent.

```
select email from emails 
order by call_count + receive_count desc;
```

to Laravel

```
DB::table('emails')
->select('email')
->orderBy(SUM('call_count','receive_count'), 'DESC')
->get();
```

Please let me know.. Thanks

Comment: Maybe something like `...orderBy(DB::raw("call_count + receive_count DESC"))` or `...orderByRaw("call_count + receive_count DESC")`  function `orderByRaw` is in the manual https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
DB::table('emails')
    ->select('email')
    ->orderBy(DB::raw("`call_count` + `receive_count`"), 'desc')
    ->get();
```