# sort by sum of multiple columns laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, equivalent

I want to ask how to orderBy some of multiple columns.
In the items table, I have 3 columns 'is_recommended', 'is_popular', 'is_new' (tags)
I want to sort by the total number of tags for each row. For examples

```
id=1 has is_recommended=1, is_popular=1, is_new=1 => attributes = 3
id=2 has is_recommended=0, is_popular=0, is_new=1 => attributes = 1
id=3 has is_recommended=1, is_popular=0, is_new=1 => attributes = 2
```

Therefore, the order will be id2, id3, id1.
My code:

```
$items = Item::addSelect(['attributes' => Item::selectRaw('`is_recommended` + `is_popular` + `is_new` as attributes')])
        ->sortable()
        ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->with('item_category', 'restaurant')->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate sum of two columns in order by clause - laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874443/calculate-sum-of-two-columns-in-order-by-clause-laravel)

Comment: Yes, I tried but it had the exception: ::getCollection() does not exist

Comment: Use raw expression for sorting.

Comment: use `->paginate(20)` instead of `->get()` in the question answer

Comment: sorry you but I think it cannot solve my problem.

Comment: I solved my problem
$items = Item::select('*',DB::raw(' `is_recommended` + `is_popular` + `is_new` AS  `attributes`'))
            ->sortable()
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->with('item_category', 'restaurant')->paginate(20);

Comment: that does not sort by your column, orderBy() should be orderBy('attributes')